# git fetch https://<access-token>url-to-repo :git-branch not working

Tags: git, subprocess, python-3.7, git-fetch

I have a git repo with master and branch1. 
on branch1- I cloned in two locations and I have to reset it to one previous commit in one location and then force push it to remote and fetch it to another location and reset it. I have to do it in some python script with subprocess. As I am able to reset in location1 and force push to remote, but I am not able to fetch it in location2 with the access token in https URL. If I could give credentials directly it works fine but not with access token URL.

Tried: `git fetch https://<access-token>@repo-url :origin/branch1`
which outputs

> - branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD

but origin/branch1 didn't go to the commit where the remote head is there, so I am not able to reset that specific commit.
while:

```
  git fetch
  prompt - username <entered>
  prompt - password <entered>
```

makes origin/branch1 to the commit where I want and then I able to reset to it.

I expect some way to run `git fetch` command (can include credentials or access-token) and fetch the remote changes on branch1 so that I can reset it. As I am running from python subprocess, I couldn't provide credentials for the prompt.

Comment: You don't need to fetch "in a branch" in git. You just fetch from a remote and all known branches on that remotes are taken as source to update your (local, but not really yours) remote-tracking branches. Then you can easily merge/rebase/reset all you want to obtain the desired state for **your local branches**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `git fetch https://<access-token>@repo-url :origin/branch1`

The arguments to `git fetch` are:

- the name of a remote ... or, if you're going to be stubborn, you *can* use a raw URL here instead of the name of a remote, and that's what you've done;
- any number of *refspecs*.  You have used one refspec, specifically `:origin/branch1`.

Refspecs have a general form of `src:dst`, where the *`src`* part is the name of a reference—e.g., a branch or tag name—found in the *source* repository, and *`dst`* is the name found in your own repository.  (This may be prefixed by a force-flag `+`.)  In this case you *omitted* the source and provided only a destination.  Since you're using `git fetch`, the other Git is the source.  So here, **you have not provided the name of the branch in the source repository** and `git fetch` will not attempt to guess.

If you wish to use their `branch1` as the source of your `origin/branch1`, provide a correct refspec.  It's wise to use *full* reference names as well:

```
git fetch <url> refs/heads/branch1:refs/remotes/origin/branch1
```

for example.

A standard fetch, using a remote name instead of a URL, obtains the default refspec from the `remote.name.fetch` setting.  For a remote named `origin` this is typically:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

so that `git fetch origin` obtains *all* of their branch names (`refs/heads/*`), and uses those to *forcibly* update all of your corresponding remote-tracking names (`refs/remotes/origin/*`, with the `*` being filled in appropriately automatically).  If the reason you're providing a raw URL, rather than the remote name `origin`, is that you need to insert the access token, you can do this *and* extract the `remote.origin.fetch` setting.  For example:

```
p = subprocess.run(["git", "config", "--get-all", "remote.origin.fetch"],
    capture_output=True, text=True)
# for python 3.6 or earlier, use
#   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True

p.check_returncode()
if p.stderr != "":
    ... do something here ...
refspecs = p.stdout.rstrip('\n').split('\n')
```

You can now add `refspecs` (a list of strings) to your `git fetch` arguments.

---

Alternatively, if you must do this often, you might just add a remote that has the desired access token in it.  Note that you can configure the fetch refspec of an alternative remote to overwrite `refs/remotes/origin/*` even if the new remote is named something other than `origin`.  For instance:

```
git remote add tokenized-origin <url-with-token>
git config remote.tokenized-origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

and then just:

```
git fetch tokenized-origin
```

whenever you want to do this update using the URL-with-embedded-token.

Comment: I upvoted because your answer solved my problem! I was doing `git fetch https://user:pass@repo.git/` which did not work. Trying `git fetch https://user:pass@repo.git/ refs/heads/branch:refs/remotes/origin/branch` worked.